# PHP htaccess Redirect url with query string from uppercase to lowercase

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this small php script and couple lines in htaccess to redirect urls with query strings from uppercase to lowercase.

However, it redirects uppercase characters in query string to lowercase ones only if there is an uppercase character in the url file or directory part of the url.

**Example with uppercase directory:**

```
domain.com/JOBS/?position=Java+Developer
```

will be redirected to

```
domain.com/jobs/?position=java+developer
```

**Example with no uppercase in directory or file name, but only in query string:**

```
domain.com/jobs/?position=Java+Developer
```

will be redirected to

```
domain.com/jobs/?position=Java+Developer
```

The first example successfully redirects the directory and the query string to all lowercase.

The second example does not redirect the query string to lowercase, it remains the same.

I can't figure out what to change in the code to get the query string to redirect to lowercase no matter if the directory or file name is uppercase or not.

Here is the code:

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# force url to lowercase if upper case is found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'])) {
    $url = $_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'];
    unset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url']);
    $params = http_build_query($_GET);
    if(strlen($params)) {
        $params = '?' . strtolower($params);
    }
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . strtolower($url) . $params, true, 301);
    exit;
}
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die('Unable to convert the URL to lowercase. You must supply a URL to work upon.');
?>
```

Comment: +1 for a well drafted question showing all the code.

Comment: After redirecting uppercase to lowercase for query string, another question regarding redirecting query string parameter to new query string with an extra parameter may be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034580/htaccess-rewrite-rule-to-add-another-parameter-to-url-query-string-or-use-php-to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$params = http_build_query($_GET);
```

use it like this:

```
$params = strtolower ( http_build_query($_GET) );
```

And your .htaccess should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force url to lowercase if upper case is found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

Since you should be calling your PHP handler for both the cases.

Comment: thanks. I tried that and it still only works if uppercase is in directory.

Comment: that did the trick. You're a good programmer. I have one last thing you might be able to help with in my htaccess if you are willing to help? Let me know. My query string now has a new parameter. I need to redirect all old query string to new query string. example: `?position=Java+Developer` now needs to be `?occupation=Developer&position=Java+Developer` Can you help? I have 11 occupations. How would I match up the occupation to the position in htaccess?

Comment: Are they always separated by `+` like `?position=Project+Manager` to become `?occupation=Manager&position=Project+Manager` ?

Comment: sometimes the structure is like this `?position=Project-Manager+or+IT-Manager` or like this `?position=Project-Manager` with a - instead of +

Comment: Hmm that makes it quite difficult for `mod_rewrite` as query string varies so much. `position=Project-Manager+or+IT-Manager` has both `-` and `+` as separator. Can this be assumed that it is always the last word?

Comment: also I should point out that on rare instances in example above, `?position=Project-Manager` is like this `?position=Manager+of+Project`

Comment: usually it is the last word, but in example above it is not. But it is only 1 or 2 links on entire site where it is not the last word.

Comment: Alright then no rewrite rule can handle that. You need to handle it in PHP as you're doing for lowering the URLs. Feel free to post a new question for those requirements with few examples.

Comment: Yes sure do link it, that way users have full context while trying to answer it.

Comment: ok no prob. just noticed one last issue with your answer. It now escapes the + in the query string to `%2b`

Comment: That is hex value of `+`. You can do `urldecode` in PHP OR try update rule.

Comment: I'd need to update rule, because the rule is firing even if there are no uppercase in the url or query string. How can I fire the rule only if it finds a uppercase?

Comment: That's not correct. `/jobs/?position=java+developer` doesn't fire this rule and I have tested it,

Comment: if I remove the htaccess rules above, then I do not have to add the urldecode to the php script `$params = strtolower(urldecode( http_build_query($_GET)) );` but if I keep the rules, and navigate my site, all urls are already in lowercase, no rewriting necessary, but the query strings have `%2b` instead of `+`. If I remove the rules above, the `+` returns as normal. Why would this be?

Comment: I can see it only fires on uppercase `[A-Z]` but why does having this rule cause `%2b` when navigating my site?

Comment: `$_GET["position"]` in PHP code gives me: `Java Developer` You can do `print_r($_GET);` on top of your PHP code to check that.

Comment: with some testing, I finally fixed the issue. I had other rules in the htaccess that needed to be placed above the new rules. Here is the link to my new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034580/htaccess-rewrite-rule-to-add-another-parameter-to-url-query-string-or-use-php-to