# htaccess rewrite rule to add another parameter to url query string or use php to handle?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My question is, How do I redirect my old query string urls to the new query string urls.

Examples below:

I have updated my query string in url like so

```
computerhelpwanted.com/jobs/?position=Oracle+Developer
```

to the following

```
computerhelpwanted.com/jobs/?occupation=Developer&position=Oracle+Developer
```

Sometimes the query string structure is like this with a `-` separating the words.

```
computerhelpwanted.com/jobs/?position=data-analyst
```

and on rare instances it is like this

```
computerhelpwanted.com/jobs/?position=tech-support+or+it-support+or+support-technician+or+support-tech
```

Most of the time it is the `+` separating the words. And in most cases the 11 occupations that can be selected will be on the end of the query string parameter like in the example for `position=Oracle+Developer`. Where Developer is the occupation.

Any help on this in mod rewrite and/or php I'd be very grateful.

Comment: So is the `occupation` always `Developer` or does that come from the `Oracle+Developer`?

Comment: no there are 11 occupations so far. Developer is just 1. There is also Engineer, Designer, Analyst, etc. The occupation parameter comes from the _get form select element. Two selects, 1 for occupation and the other for position. I might add that there are not always 2 words in the position parameter. Sometimes there are 3 or 4 like in the last example above.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're actually asking for then... If all the query string params are already populated what do you want to rewrite?

Comment: Better would be to do this in PHP. Split query string by `+` or `-` and then check against a known list from DB.

Comment: there are links indexed on Google that I need to redirect to the new query strings. `?occupation=` is the new parameter in the query string.

Comment: is this possible with htaccess? if done in php, can you give me a sample code?

Comment: I did the PHP route which worked out better.