# How to redirect uppercase url query string to lowercase in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I recently changed the URL parameters in my query strings on a site I'm developing and need a efficient way in PHP to redirect all search engine indexed links that have query strings in them from an uppercase format to a lowercase format.

Here is a example:

```
http://computerhelpwanted.com/jobs/?occupation=Director&position=IT+Director
```

Notice how the query string parameters have the first letter in uppercase, except the word IT is all uppercase. I need to redirect to the lowercase version of the URL which is now what the site uses.

I tried out a htaccess + php work around but it is causing too many issues. Here's the link if you're interested in seeing that script. https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2012/11/force-lowercase-urls-rewrite-php.html as well as the question on stackoverflow when I was having issues with it [PHP htaccess Redirect url with query string from uppercase to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032665/php-htaccess-redirect-url-with-query-string-from-uppercase-to-lowercase)

So for this question, if possible I just want to stick with a pure PHP way of doing this. Unless you know of a way in htaccess without using httpd.conf or mapping or mod spelling because I do not have access to that.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != strtolower ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) )
    header ('Location: //' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . strtolower ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ));
```

This will redirect to the lowercase version of the URI only if it is not already in lower case. The // at the start is replaced by the browser to the actual url schema.

Comment: this one works too except for the trailing // you put in the beginning makes the url structure have 2 trailing slashes after the directory. Georg used preg_match [A-Z]. Which will perform faster, your way or his?

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean with 'after the directory'. That double slash is supported by all major browser, but I just learn it is (oh surprise) [broken in IE](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). Also, I think RegExp is slower than simple byte comparison.

Comment: I'm using your suggestion because it is simpler and to the point. I mean after the directory, the folder, in this case /jobs//. It was weird.

Comment: Um, ya.. this broke my site too. It was even worse than @Mike indicated

Answer (score 2):

In pure PHP,

```
if(preg_match('~[A-Z]~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
}
```

If you want a permanent redirect:

```
header(above thing, true, 301);
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for. I only changed the header location part and took out the trailing / as it caused 2 trailing slashes to appear in the url. I formatted it like this `header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), true, 301);`

Comment: referring to my comment to drmad, which way will perform faster? preg_match or his answer?